# C library called in Golang is stuck in thread synchronization

Tags: multithreading, go, cgo

I'm writting a Golang package to manage NFC tags on an embedded system.

The tag reader is based on a NXP chip and a library from NXP : https://github.com/NXPNFCLinux/linux_libnfc-nci/tree/NCI2.0_PN7160. NXP also provides an example to read tags with that library : https://github.com/NXPNFCLinux/linux_libnfc-nci_examples/blob/master/tag-read_example/main.c.

The example works as expected and I'm able to read tags' information.

My Golang package uses cgo to call the functions in that C library. To enable the NFC discovery mode the following sequence must be done (as in the example):

1. `nfcManager_doInitialize()`
2. `nfcManager_registerTagCallback(...)`
3. `nfcManager_enableDiscovery(...)`

My golang package is stuck in the function `nfcManager_enableDiscovery(...)`. After some investigation I figured out that the function is blocked when waiting for an event coming from another thread (https://github.com/NXPNFCLinux/linux_libnfc-nci/blob/NCI2.0_PN7160/src/nxp_nci_hal_nfc/nci/jni/NativeNfcManager.cpp#L2461).

The code `sNfaEnableDisablePollingEvent.wait()` is waiting for a mutex to be notified. It is calling `pthread_cond_wait`.

I tried to use [`runtime.LockOSThread`](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/LockOSThread) but it doesn't fix my issue. I have checked that all the C functions called from my Go package have their paremters set with the right values, and it is the case.

Any idea on how to fix it ?